# How to prevent user changing system date/time in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate

I use `[NSDate date]` to get user's system time, but if the user changed system date/time, I'll get a error date. How can I solve this problem?

ps : `[NSDate date]` is the only way to get the date from user's iPhone, and user has no network.

Comment: I think there is no way, if your app doesn't connect and sync datetime with your server

Comment: Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588243/can-i-prevent-an-ios-user-from-changing-the-date-and-time Instead you locals to get the right date format.

Comment: thanks. That's right I want answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an auxiliary measure, you can get **true time from server** when network is accessible. That is, when app has access to network, don`t trust in local system time. However, that is just merely an assistant measure. It can not be sure that network is always connected. In my opinion, in summary, **there is no absolute way to prevent system data changing, but we can use server time to weaken its negative effect.**

Comment: thanks. I thought of another solution, if can be solved with timer？I from a timer to get time without ` [NSDate date] ` get time

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent the user from changing the system date or time.